# Submit form with ajax in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, templates

I am trying to create jquery function which send my html form with ajax. I build standard html form with POST method and now I am trying to create jquery part and there is a problem. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function() {
    var formData = $('form').serialize();
    var href = 'http://stravomat.michalfolprecht.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
    $.post(href, formData, function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
            if ( resp.success ) {
                console.log('success');

            } else {
                console.log('alert');
            }
        });

    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

I have php part on the same page where is the form and this is standard wordpress custom page template. Jquery code is in custom file and linked to wordpress header. I do not know if I should use ajax url or use url page. When I try to use this code console log give me number 0  that's all. Can you someone help me with this?

Thanks for reply.

Michal.

Answer (score 0):

As per WordPress structure

You will need to pass `action` variable alongwith the form and define a function in WordPress plugin/theme to catch that action using add_action method.

see for more details: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: If I understand well I have to use functions.php and create there jquery code and user add_action is that right?

Comment: And if in codex is headline "Ajax on administration side" can I used this code also in frontend not only in backend?

Comment: yes, check section Ajax on the Viewer-Facing Side in same page.